# Tor Browser doesn't survive gnome-shell restart

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, ubuntu

Tor Browser 11.0.9 on stock Ubuntu 20.04 with Gnome 3.36
I don't remember when it happened, but now Tor Browser is closed on gnome-shell restart (via alt-F2: r).
I remember that it survived it earlier (as all other apps do on X11 for years).

What happened and can it be fixed?